# Magento2: Where to place the grand-total.html in my theme?

Tags: magento2

i have made some changes in:

```
vendor/⁨magento⁩/module-tax⁩/view⁩/frontend/web⁩/⁨template⁩/⁨checkout⁩/⁨cart⁩/⁨totals/grand-total.html
```

Where should i place it in my own theme? Nothing is working. What i acually have is:

```
app/⁨design/⁨frontend/⁨VENDOR/⁨VENDORTHEME⁩/⁨Magento_Tax/⁨template/⁨checkout/⁨cart/⁨totals⁩/grand-total.html
```

But without any success....

Comment: which version of magento ? i don't find grand-total.html in location you provide

Comment: Magento Version 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

> app/⁨design/⁨frontend/Vendor/themename/⁨Magento_Tax/⁨⁨web/template/checkout/⁨cart/⁨totals⁩/grand-total.html

Comment: Thanks for your tip. But it wont work...

Comment: If you're sure of the module that you need to override, it should work

Comment: flush cash and clean var\view_preprocessed folder

Comment: Hi Prince. Nope... Have c:c, c:f, deleted var/view_preprocessed etc... not working